# How can i save data with Hive?

Tags: flutter, flutter-hive

Thanks for reading my question.

I watched videos and read HiveDB docs. But still I am not sure how to do save value when it is changed.

The below code is my `timer`code.

After an hour, `coins` value is changed.

I want to save that value with HiveDB, What should I do?

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:dubu_timer/hive_model.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:hive/hive.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:dubu_timer/provider/global_provider.dart';
import 'package:hive_flutter/hive_flutter.dart';

class Pomodoro extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PomodoroState createState() => _PomodoroState();
}

class _PomodoroState extends State<Pomodoro> {
  double coinCount = 0;
  Stopwatch watch = Stopwatch();
  Timer? timer;
  bool startStop = true;

  String elapsedTime = '';

  @override
  void dispose() {
    timer?.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  updateTime(Timer timer) {
    if (watch.isRunning) {
      setState(() {
        elapsedTime = transformMilliSeconds(watch.elapsedMilliseconds);
      });
      if (coinCount == 360000) {
        context.read<Counts>().add(1); //generate 1 coin after an hour!
        coinCount = 0;
      } else {
        coinCount = coinCount + 10;
      }
      context.read<Times>().timeAdd(100); //Add 1 sec on focused Time
    }
  }

  restartTimer() {
    updateTime(timer!).cancel();
    setState(() {
      startStop = true;
      watch.stop();
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 0,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back, color: Colors.black),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).pop();
          },
        ),
      ),
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(elapsedTime,
                style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Kitto', fontSize: 25.0)),
            SizedBox(height: 20.0),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                IconButton(
                  splashColor: Colors.transparent,
                  highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
                  onPressed: () async {
                    startOrStop();
                    },
                  icon: Image.asset('assets/button.png'),
                  iconSize: 50,
                )
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  startOrStop() {
    if (startStop) {
      startWatch();
    } else {
      stopWatch();
    }
  }

  startWatch() {
    setState(() {
      startStop = false;
      watch.start();
      timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(milliseconds: 100), updateTime);
    });
  }

  stopWatch() {
    setState(() {
      startStop = true;
      watch.stop();
      setTime();
    });
  }

  setTime() {
    var timeSoFar = watch.elapsedMilliseconds;
    setState(() {
      elapsedTime = transformMilliSeconds(timeSoFar);
    });
  }

  transformMilliSeconds(int milliseconds) {
    int hundreds = (milliseconds / 10).truncate();
    int seconds = (hundreds / 100).truncate();
    int minutes = (seconds / 60).truncate();
    int hours = (minutes / 60).truncate();

    String hoursStr = (hours % 60).toString().padLeft(2, '0');
    String minutesStr = (minutes % 60).toString().padLeft(2, '0');
    String secondsStr = (seconds % 60).toString().padLeft(2, '0');

    return "$hoursStr:$minutesStr:$secondsStr";
  }
}
```

and this is my hivedb model!

```
import 'package:hive_flutter/hive_flutter.dart';
import 'package:hive/hive.dart';

part 'hive_model.g.dart';

@HiveType(typeId: 0)
class HiveModel {
  @HiveField(0)
  int coins;

  @HiveField(1)
  List<String> ownedItems;

  @HiveField(2)
  int focusedTime;

  HiveModel({
    required this.coins,
    required this.focusedTime,
    required this.ownedItems,
  });
}
```

I hope you can help newbie!

Thanks for reading and I'm waiting your response!

Have a nice day!

Comment: https://medium.flutterdevs.com/hive-database-with-typeadapter-in-flutter-7390d0e515fa